# Countries Array check for value

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm looking for a solution to check an array if country-code exists.
And than post the whole name.

I'm new in PHP so I'm not shure if in_array is the right way :)

The php code

```
$country = "al"

<?php if (in_array("$country", $countries_en)) {
        echo "$country"; }
    ?>
```

So the echo what i want is not "al". I want "Albania".

***The array:***

```
$countries_en = array
(
    'ad' => 'Andorra',
    'ae' => 'United Arab Emirates',
    'af' => 'Afghanistan',
    'ag' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'ai' => 'Anguilla',
    'al' => 'Albania',
    'am' => 'Armenia,..... and much more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$country` as the key to get the value you want from the `$country_en` array:

```
$country = "al";

if (array_key_exists($country, $countries_en)) {
    echo $country_en[$country]; 
}
```

You want to use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) here, not `in_array()` as `al` is one of the array keys, not a value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Here "al" is used as key of array, not value and **in_array()** function checks for value.

So, you need to use another function **array_key_exists()** here.

```
<?php if (array_key_exists($country, $countries_en)) {
    echo $country_en[$country]; }
?>
```

Comment: Well, isn't this just the same as [John's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22688407/1438393) above? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet
  <?php 
   $country='al';
   if(isset($countries_en[$country]))
   { 
         echo $countries_en[$country];
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function:

```
$country = 'ai';

$countries_en = array(
    'ad' => 'Andorra',
    'ae' => 'United Arab Emirates',
    'af' => 'Afghanistan',
    'ag' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'ai' => 'Anguilla'
);

array_walk($countries_en, function($value,$key) use ($country) {
    if ($country === $key) {
        echo $value; // result "Anguilla"
    }
});
```

Comment: An alternative approach. But I feel `array_walk` overkill here as a simple key look-up can solve the issue. The function has to iterate through the entire array to perform whatever operation you're defining inside the `callback`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, it is alternative one and suppose OP find it interesting as long as he need to manipulate thoughout the array

Comment: I +1'd your answer already. I've updated your answer to use the `use` construct (which is the correct way to access variables outside the callback function scope).